# Bash user input while not match variable loop

Tags: bash, loops, user-input

I'm trying to get a user input to loop until the input/name is unique (not contained in output/variable).

I've tried to do something like this, which I thought would have worked:

```
read -p "$QlabelName" input
while [[ "$input" == "$(/usr/sbin/networksetup -listallnetworkservices |grep "$input")" ]]; do
read -p "Name already in use, please enter a unique name:" input
done
```

I've also tried putting the `$(/usr/sbin/networksetup -listallnetworkservices |grep "$input")` bit into a variable itself and then using the condition `[[ "$input" == "GREPVARIABLE" ]]` without success.

Original user input menu, without loop (working):

```
labelName=NJDC
QlabelName=$(echo Please enter the name of connection to be displayed from within the GUI [$labelName]: )
read -p "$QlabelName" input
labelName="${input:-$labelName}"
echo "The connection name will be set to: '$labelName'"
```

I've tried a variety of solutions from SO, Unix, ServerFault, etc with no success. I've tried `if`, `while`, `until`, `!=`, `==`, `=~` as well with no success.

I've confirmed with simple debug `echo`'s at each step that variables contain the data, but the loop is not working.

**EDIT** (solution, in context to the question, thanks to @LinuxDisciple's answer):

```
labelName=NJDC
QlabelName=$(echo Please enter the name of connection to be displayed from within the GUI [$labelName]: )
read -p "$QlabelName" input
while /usr/sbin/networksetup -listallnetworkservices |grep -q "^${input}$"; do
    read -p "Name already in use, please enter a unique name:" input
done
labelName="${input:-$labelName}"
echo "The connection name will be set to: '$labelName'"
```

This was important to me to keep default variable values for `labelName` and output the correct information to the user.

Comment: i just tried a simplified version of your loop (using a cat command instead of the networksetup command) and it worked as expected.  please post your input, expected results, and actual results.

Comment: @JEarls Hmm, I'd also tried to `cat` the command/grep into a variable. Can you share how you'd crafted it?

Comment: `echo` isn't a good way to debug this issue because you won't be able to tell whether the variable has trailing spaces or control characters that will affect matching. You can use `printf '%q\n' "$variable"` to see an unambiguous representation.

Comment: `QlabelName=$(echo ...)` is unnecessary; just use `Qlabelname=...`.

Comment: @chepner will that preserve the [default] variable value? Also, it's `echo`ing out to STOUT as a bash prompt waiting for user input. Wouldn't `Qlabelname=...` simply make the statement a variable?

Comment: It already is a variable. `$(...)` just captures the output of the enclosed command and uses it as a string.

Comment: @chepner That doesn't work for me. This is part of a larger bash menu, but even running it on its own to test, it does not preserve the variable defaults. Anyway, don't think it's pertinent to the issue I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: Did you use quotes? `QlabelName="Please enter ... [$labelName]: "`

Comment: I did use quotes. It didn't preserve the default value or pass it on to the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read -p "$QlabelName" input
while /usr/sbin/networksetup -listallnetworkservices |grep -q "^${input}$"; do
    read -p "Name already in use, please enter a unique name:" input
done
```

`grep`'s return code is good enough for `while`, and since we don't want to actually *see* the output, we can use `-q` to suppress it. You can also run it without `-q` to see what grep actually found until you're satisfied that it's running correctly.

For further debuggability, I would pipe the output to `cat -A`. You can echo your variable value in the while-loop and just add `|cat -A` immediately after the `done` and it should show all the characters:

```
read -p "$QlabelName" input
while /usr/sbin/networksetup -listallnetworkservices |grep -q "^${input}$"; do
    read -p "Name already in use, please enter a unique name:" input
    echo "Input was:'$input'"
done |cat -A
```

Comment: Working straight off the bat with your `grep -q "^${input}$"` suggestion. Very nice! Thank you very much! Also, the pipe to `cat -A` is a useful tip to know. Thanks again.